# Using jq to "normalize" JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use jq to "normalize" JSON so that given the input:

```
[
    [                                                                            
      {"M":6, "C":66, "R":0.1},      
      {"M":6, "C":81, "R":0.9}
    ],
    [    
      {"M":11, "C":94, "R":0.8},    
      {"M":11, "C":55, "R":0.46}     
    ]
    ,
    ...
]
```

the output should be:

```
[
    {
        "M" : 6,
        "X" : [{"66" : 0.1},{"81": 0.9}]
    },
    {
        "M" : 11,
        "X" : [{"94" : 0.8},{"55": 0.46}]
    },
    ...

]
```

I can extract M with `map({M: .[0].M` but not sure how to proceed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
[foreach .[] as $list ({};
  {
    "M": $list[0].M,
    "X": [foreach $list[] as $item ({};
            {"\($item.C)": $item.R}
         )]
  }
)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `X` to the result of mapping over the array and creating a one-element object for each entry, with `C` as the key and `R` as the value.

```
map({M: .[0].M, X: map({"\(.C)": .R})})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `map(f)` is defined as `[.[]|f]`, here is an expanded form of [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899165/santiago-lapresta)'s solution with some additional comments:

```
[                             # compute result array from
  .[]                         #   scaning input array
| {  M: .[0].M                #   compute M from the .M of the first element
   , X: [                     #   compute X array from
         .[]                  #     scanning each element's objects
       | {"\(.C)":.R}         #     and constructing new {C:R} objects
     ]                        
  }
]
```